# Cross origin read blocking is blocking the response when I am using an API to retrieve GIFs

Tags: cross-domain, cross-origin-read-blocking

When I am running my web app then the following error gets displayed on the console:

Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://tenor.com/view/claire-dancing-baby-sunglasses-toddler-gif-11410651 with MIME type text/HTML. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

I am trying to figure out the issue but not finding any solution which I am able to understand.

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://tenor.com/view/claire-dancing-baby-sunglasses-toddler-gif-11410651 with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

I expect to get the GIF URLs from the API response.